# Creating Geo points in Kibana

Tags: json, elasticsearch, kibana

how i can create geo points in Kibana after i already imported my data from SQL into Elastic, as i want to add new field called location for latitude and longitude so i can be able to use the maps visualizations or modify the index i have created. thank

sample of my index

```
 {
        "_index": "test1",
        "_type": "pre-test",
        "_id": "AVk1OzrXZxCtOaXERUPg",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "tagno": "L116E11079                ",
          "status": "04 ",
          "cdesc": "STRINGING                                         ",
          "statusdt": "2016-08-27T00:00:00",
          "weightdone": 12.35,
          "cchiange": "0067+172.750   ",
          "kp_no": "067",
          "latitude": 29.55592659,
          "longitude": 47.69675638,
          "pIPELINE": " FUEL ",
          "pIPELINE_DESCRIPTION": "From A ",
          "pOINT_DESCRIPTION": "KILOMETER POINT (KP)",
          "cATEGORY": "MAIN "
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to map the field as Geo point and than index the documents, look at [geopoint documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/geo-point.html)